# Deploying More Jar files (Own) in server

Tags: jar

I am new to deployment and development of web applications.

Suppose I create three jar files and deploy them on a Tomcat server. I use maven to install the jar file and to deploy.

How is it possible to call a method in another jar file?

For example: 
I developed a simple application in `mytwitter.jar`.
Then, I create `myapp.jar`, where one of the classes needs to call a method in `mytwitter.jar`.

Do I first deploy `mytwitter.jar` to the server and `myapp.jar` later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You package all of the JARs you need (yours and 3rd party alike) into a WAR file which is what gets deployed to the Tomcat server. So in your maven config you likely already have dependencies configured for things like the twitter API and other packages. Just add your own JARs in there as well and then your code has access to it like anything else.